# Catkin-configuration error

Tags: catkin, catkin-workspace, ros-workspace

I am using  ROS2 humble, Linux version 22.04 trying to build the system with catkin-tools in that getting error at the configure the workspace

```
VirtualBox:/tmp/catkin_ws$ catkin config --extend /opt/ros/humble/

Error: Could not configure catkin workspace: Cannot load environment from 
resultspace "/opt/ros/humble" because it does not appear to be a catkin-
generated resultspace (missing .catkin marker file).
```

Thanks..

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! It seems that your installation is incomplete or broken. I suggest reinstalling ROS

Comment: Thankyou for responding ... But I tried to reinstall, same error is repeating